# Why is my keyframe not functioning correctly when my app is served statically?

Tags: css, reactjs, express

I'm creating a ReactJS app and deploying it on an ExpressJS back-end. The app functions perfectly in the development build, but once the webpage is served statically the keyframes don't behave the same way. I am trying to fade/focus in a piece of text by changing its opacity. The webpage sets the opacity to 0 at the beginning, completely skips the middle-part of the animation, and ends by changing the opacity to 100% once completed (1 second keyframe). In the development build, the effect I get is actually a true fade/focus. How can I fix this issue?

Relevant CSS:

```
.introduction {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 20px 20% 50px 20%;
}
.text_1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-overflow: normal;
    font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
    animation: focus 1s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.text_highlight {
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.text_highlight:hover {
    color: rgb(176, 80, 255);
    transition: color 1.0s;
}
@keyframes focus {
    from { opacity: 0%; }
    to { opacity: 100%; }
}
```